# Reverse breakdown voltage setting for the diodes in a solar cell model in SPICE

Tags: diodes, spice, ltspice

I want to simulate the reverse breakdown behavior of a two diode model solar cell in SPICE.
The diodes configurations without considering the breakdown voltage are as below:

```
.model diode d( Is=1.5e-10,  xti=3)
.model diode2 d(Is=1.77e-6, n=2, xti=3)
```

With the given diodes configurations, I can simulate all characteristics before the breakdown voltage point.
[image: I-V curve without adding reverse breakdown voltage code]
By adding the breakdown voltage point to the diode model, I cannot see the curve in **forward bias** anymore and it does not work properly.

```
.model diode d( Is=1.5e-10,  xti=3, vrev=15, BV=15)
.model diode2 d(Is=1.77e-6, n=2, xti=3, vrev=15, BV=15)
```

[image]

In short, when I add the code for reverse breakdown voltage point, my diode does not work properly in forward bias! Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [LTWiki](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/D_Diode.htm):

> There are two types of diodes available. One is a conduction region-wise linear model that yields a computationally light weight representation of an idealized diode.
>
> ...
>
> This idealized model is used if any of Ron, Roff, Vfwd, Vrev or Rrev is specified in the model.

So when you included the `VREV` parameter, you changed your model to use the piecewise linear diode model instead of the usual nonlinear model. Your other parameters (`IS`, `XTI`, and `BV`) are ignored and the piecewise linear model parameters that you didn't specify take their default values.. This could make a substantial change to the operating behavior of the diodes in your model.

Comment: Thank very much. Now it works properly. Since I have less than 15 reputations, I cannot vote your answer so please accept my thanks here.